# Selenium not returning the correct number of child elements?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying multiple ways to get the child elements of this section, but it seems to be wildly off.
The website I'm using is https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-bsc/57997898 except I am to do this multiple times over multiple pages so I'm just focusing on making sure that just one webpage can return what I need.
Currently this is what I have:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('--headless')

driver = Chrome(options = opts, executable_path = 'D:\Programs\Python\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-bsc/57997898")

closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='closeFilter']")
closeButton.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='acceptCookie']").click()

modules_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-sub-sec='Modules']").find_element_by_class_name("cdsb_rt")
numberOfModulesByYear = len(modules_container.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdldv']"))

for moduleYear in range(numberOfModulesByYear):
      print("_"*75)
      moduleYearButtonString = "//div[@class='mdldv' and @data-module-sections='{}']".format(str(moduleYear))
      module_year = modules_container.find_element_by_xpath(moduleYearButtonString)
      module_year_a = module_year.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
      while module_year_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class") != "icon icon-minus": 
            module_year_a.click()
            print(module_year_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class"))
      numberOfModules = module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")
      print(len(numberOfModules))

driver.close()
```

The output is:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
icon icon-minus
0
___________________________________________________________________________
icon icon-minus
10
___________________________________________________________________________
icon icon-minus
10
___________________________________________________________________________
icon icon-minus
15
```

However, in order of modules on the website it's 5,5,4,1
Does anyone know how to fix this?
(Also appears to me that Selenium is not looking *exclusively* within the element for child elements and also is returning child elements in its sibling elements which is *NOT* what I want.

Edit: Still have no idea why it's returning sibling child elements but I figured I would hav eto wait for it load:

```
for moduleYear in range(numberOfModulesByYear):
      print("_"*75)
      moduleYearButtonString = "//div[@class='mdldv' and @data-module-sections='{}']".format(str(moduleYear))
      module_year = modules_container.find_element_by_xpath(moduleYearButtonString)
      module_year_a = module_year.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
      while module_year_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class") != "icon icon-minus": 
            module_year_a.click()
      while len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")) - previousNumberOfModules == 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
      numberOfModules = len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")) - previousNumberOfModules
      previousNumberOfModules = len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']"))
      print(numberOfModules)
```

Still have no idea why it's returning sibling child elements though, when I specified the exact element I want it to look inside of.

Comment: I see 5,4,1 in terms of sections by year. Can you make it clearer exactly what should be returned from that page?

Comment: I'm trying to get all of module names and descriptions under them (if they have one)

Answer (score 2):

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('--headless')

driver = Chrome(executable_path = 'D:\Programs\Python\chromedriver.exe', options = opts)

driver.get("https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-bsc/57997898")

closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='closeFilter']")
closeButton.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='acceptCookie']").click()

modules_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-sub-sec='Modules']").find_element_by_class_name("cdsb_rt")
numberOfModulesByYear = len(modules_container.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdldv']"))
previousNumberOfModules = 0
numberOfModulesTab = []

print("-"*100)
for moduleYear in range(numberOfModulesByYear):
      moduleYearButtonString = "//div[@class='mdldv' and @data-module-sections='{}']".format(str(moduleYear))
      module_year = modules_container.find_element_by_xpath(moduleYearButtonString)
      print(module_year.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
      module_year_a = module_year.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      while module_year_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class") == "icon icon-add": 
            module_year_a.click()
      while len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")) - previousNumberOfModules == 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
      listOfModules = module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")
      numberOfModules = len(listOfModules) - previousNumberOfModules
      previousNumberOfModules = len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']"))
      numberOfModulesTab.append(numberOfModules)
      print("-"*100)

alreadyExistingModules = []
moduleIndex = 0
numberOfDescriptions = 0

allTheModules = modules_container.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")
for moduleNumber, module in enumerate(allTheModules):
      outputLines = False
      module_a = module.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
      if len(module_a) > 0:
            module_a = module_a[0]
            soup = BSoup(module_a.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser")
            moduleName = soup.find("span", class_='mdltxt').getText()
            if not (moduleName in alreadyExistingModules):
                  outputLines = True
                  moduleIndex += 1
                  alreadyExistingModules.append(moduleName)
                  print(moduleName.rstrip())
                  while module_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class") == "icon icon-add":
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", module_a)
                  while len(module.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='mdesc']"))-numberOfDescriptions == 0:
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                  soup = BSoup(module.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser")
                  print(soup.find("p", class_="mdesc").getText().rstrip())
                  numberOfDescriptions += 1
      else:
            soup = BSoup(module.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser")
            moduleName = soup.find("span", class_='mtxt').getText()
            if not (moduleName in alreadyExistingModules):
                  outputLines = True
                  moduleIndex += 1
                  alreadyExistingModules.append(moduleName)
                  print(moduleName.rstrip())
                  
      if outputLines:
            print("-"*100)

driver.close()
```

Had to wait at certain points because java script doesn't immediately execute and sometimes executes twice... and for some reason it was returning what I didn't want so I had to use beautifulSoup to get what I wanted but it works so :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the whole thing with `requests` as the page uses ajax requests to get the module info for courses. If you visit a given course page, you can extract the module ids for the initial ajax request to get the modules; then extract the description ids for each module to use in a subsequent request.

I have used `Session` for efficiency of tcp re-use. Also, tried to abstract in hope you can use with different course id (at this point starts to feel like could re-write as class)......

```
import requests, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

course_id = '57997898'

url_desc = 'https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/cug2/ajax/get-course-modules-description.html'
url_modules = 'https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/cug2/ajax/get-course-modules.html'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-bsc/' + course_id,
}

results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    r = s.get(f'https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-bsc/{course_id}#modules')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    module_ids = {i.a.text.strip():i.select_one('.mdtt')['data-module-group'] for i in soup.select('.mdldv')} #gather the module ids

    for k,v in module_ids.items():
        results[k] = {}
        data = {'moduleGroupId': v, 'courseId': course_id}
        r = s.post(url_modules,data=data) 
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        modules = {i.select_one('.mdltxt').text.strip():i.a['data-modules-list'] 
                   for i in soup.select('.mdiv') if i.select_one('.mdltxt')}
        # print(modules)
        if modules: #check there are actually modules (last doesn't have any)
            for k2,v2 in modules.items():
                data = {'moduleGroupId': v, 'moduleId': v2}
                r = s.post(url_desc, data=data)
                soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
                desc = soup.select_one('.mdesc').text.strip()
                results[k][k2] = desc
                # print(desc)
pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: I was scared to use requests because it looked complicated but I will 100% be using this if it's faster :)

Comment: Happy to explain more if you are want me to.